# Font Awesome does not work in browser, but works in codepen

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I downloaded Font Awesome today and did it a try. In firefox and chrome (latest versions) it appears as blank squares. If a use the CDN link, it doesnt even work, the standard bullets appear instead of the blank squares. But in codepen.io, it just worked fine, using the CDN.

The html i used is just the same as the example of the lists, which is here: http://codepen.io/pietrofxq/pen/BCaoD

Does someone knows the problem?

Comment: Are the paths to your font-files correct? It's a very common problem when someone gets squares.

Comment: I missed the "http:" in CDN link. But with my own file it doesnt work. I know its being recognized because if it wasnt, the blank squares wouldnt appear at all

Answer (score 1):

You are using a schemaless URL to access the CDN.

If you are trying to open the page from your disk (*schema being `file://`*) then it will fail is it will use the same schema to access the CDN

Try with a full URL ***http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css***

---

If you are calling it from a server, then make sure that the font files are delivered correctly. Some servers need to be told to allow the font files to be accessed.
(*use the console to see if they load ok*)

Comment: I didnt see i miss the "http:". It now works, but doesnt with my own font awesome file.

Comment: @user3147789 i just copy pasted your code from codepen to a file on my desktop (*fixed the missing http*) and it works fine.. Is your code exactly the same as the one on codepen ?

Comment: i actually copied the code from my text editor to put it in codepen. I add two links: one from CDN, and another to the .css font awesome that is in the same folder, but it just appear as blank squares. In chrome too. After looking in google it seems to be a "CORS" problem